# Filter nested result inside a nested object with elasticsearch

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I'm trying to filter a nested object and sort by the result, however, I tried some things without success, I'll leave my initial attempt and it works partially, it just filters according to what I have in my search variable, but all the results come of this nested object as it is inside the 'root' which is another nested object

**Elastic version: 7.13.0 with NodeJS**
using **@elastic/elasticsearch** official package from npm

```
let params: RequestParams.Search = {
      index: index,
      body: {
        size: 30,
        query: {
          bool: {
            must: [
              {
                nested: {
                  path: "profile",
                  query: {
                    bool: {
                      must: [
                        {
                          match: {
                            "profile.id": profileId,
                          },
                        },
                      ],
                    },
                  },
                },
              },
            ],
            filter: [
              {
                nested: {
                  path: "profile.following",
                  ignore_unmapped: true,
                  query: {
                    query_string: {
                      fields: [
                        "profile.following.name",
                        "profile.following.username",
                      ],
                      query: searchWord + "*",
                    },
                  },
                },
              },
            ],
          },
        },
      },
    };
```

**I need it to be this specific 'profile.id' that is passed by parameter in the function, so the result is only 1 profile with N people that it follows**

the document is mapped as follows, I left only the fields relevant to the question:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "phone": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "profile": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "id": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "username": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "following": {
              "type": "nested",
              "properties": {
                "id": {
                  "type": "integer"
                },
                "isAwaitingApproval": {
                  "type": "boolean"
                },
                "name": {
                  "type": "text"
                },
                "profilePicURL": {
                  "type": "text"
                },
                "username": {
                  "type": "text"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

an example of a current result is:
with the following parameters (profileId:141, searchWord: "para" )

```
{
    "res": [
        {
            "profilePicURL": "localimage",
            "name": "donor donor",
            "id": 140,
            "username": "victorTesteElastic2",
            "isAwaitingApproval": false
        },
        {
            "profilePicURL": "localimage",
            "name": "para ser seguido",
            "id": 142,
            "username": "victorprivate",
            "isAwaitingApproval": true
        }
    ]
}
```

**the desired result is:**

```
{
  "res": [
      {
          "profilePicURL": "localimage",
          "name": "para ser seguido",
          "id": 142,
          "username": "victorprivate",
          "isAwaitingApproval": true
      }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with some more research I got what I needed, I'll leave the answer here in case anyone needs it too

```
let params: RequestParams.Search = {
      index: index,
      body: {
        size: 30,
        query: {
          bool: {
            must: [
              {
                nested: {
                  path: "profile",
                  query: {
                    bool: {
                      must: [
                        {
                          match: {
                            "profile.id": profileId,
                          },
                        },
                      ],
                    },
                  },
                },
              },
              {
                nested: {
                  path: "profile",
                  inner_hits: {
                    name: "profile",
                  },
                  query: {
                    nested: {
                      path: "profile.following",
                      inner_hits: {
                        name: "following",
                      },
                      ignore_unmapped: true,
                      query: {
                        query_string: {
                          fields: [
                            "profile.following.name",
                            "profile.following.username",
                          ],
                          query: searchWord + "*",
                        },
                      },
                    },
                  },
                },
              },
            ],
          },
        },
      },
    };
```

I basically put in **must** what was in the filter, mapped the nested object from above, in this case the profile, and put the tag inner_hits for profile and inner_hits for followings, that's the only way it worked

the answer I need was returned here:
**body.hits.hits[0].inner_hits.profile.hits.hits[0].inner_hits.following.hits.hits**

below is an example of the answer:

```
{
    "res": [
        {
            "_index": "donor",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "P3VWNnsB4coAEhD-F3fF",
            "_nested": {
                "field": "profile",
                "offset": 0,
                "_nested": {
                    "field": "following",
                    "offset": 0
                }
            },
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "profilePicURL": "localimage",
                "name": "donor donor",
                "id": 140,
                "username": "victorTesteElastic2",
                "isAwaitingApproval": false
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "donor",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "P3VWNnsB4coAEhD-F3fF",
            "_nested": {
                "field": "profile",
                "offset": 0,
                "_nested": {
                    "field": "following",
                    "offset": 1
                }
            },
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "profilePicURL": "localimage",
                "name": "para ser seguido",
                "id": 142,
                "username": "victorprivate",
                "isAwaitingApproval": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

the filtered data I really need that have been `matched` in `must` is in this array, where I need to iterate and look at `_source` which is the data that is indexed